# JqGrid - how to make the clear search button visible?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a filter toolbar in my JqGrid, and the Clearfield "x" hyperlink is not showing. There is not enough room for the ui-search-clear cell to show.
If I could control the size of the input textbox for the search inside the cell with the class ui-search-input then it would show.
I would have thought this would work by default.
So how do I fix this?
My grid is defined as follows;

```
var populateGrid = function (data) {
    var grid = $("#grid");
    grid.jqGrid({
        data: data,
        colNames: ["No", "Company", "Trade", "Recommendation", ""],
        colModel: [
            { name: "AssessmentNo", label: "AssessmentNo", width:80, align:"center" },
            { name: "Company", label: "Company", width:400, searchoptions: { sopt: ["cn"] } },
            { name: "Trade", label: "Trade", width: 220, searchoptions: { sopt: ["cn"] } },
            { name: "Recommendation", label: "Recommendation", width: 150 },
            { name: "Links", label: "Links", search: false, align: "center" }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { width: 100, autoResizable: true },
        loadonce: true,
        forceClientSorting: true,
        rowNum: 20,
        pager: "#pager",
        gridview: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        rownumbers: true,
        sortname: "AssessmentNo",
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        height: "100%"
    });

    grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
        beforeSearch: function () {
            return false; // allow filtering
        }
    }).jqGrid("gridResize");
}
```

And my toolbar looks like;
[image]

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid? You included `forceClientSorting: true` option, which exists only in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, but I can't reproduce the problem in free jqGrid (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa2.htm) for example). Could you provide the demo which reproduces your problem?

Comment: I am using jqGrid 4.13.2, the free version.

Comment: **Could you provide the demo, which reproduces your problem?** I suppose that *other CSS* which you include on the page could make some problems.

Comment: I have put in the HTML of the headers of the grid from IE developer's tools in the question.

Comment: I can't see how to put JqGrid into JsFiddle

Comment: You need just search in Google for videos about the usage of JsFiddle. The GUI is changed a little, but the main place stay unchanged: click on "External Resources" on the left side and include URL to any CSS or JS files. By clicking on the "JavaScript" (see in the middle) you can include some common libraries (if you don't want to search for URLs to there) and to define Load Type of the included JavaScript code from the JavaScript window. It's all. You can find here https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/5w5h2Lgw/6/ an example of the usage free jqGrid. http://doc.jsfiddle.net/ contains the documentation

Comment: Is there are any progress in the problem, which you reports? Is it solved already?

Comment: @Oleg I just read your profile I am just wowed :)

Comment: @SachinDivakar: Thank you! You motto "Trying to learn something new every day about it" is very good too. I do the same.

Comment: @Oleg but I am nowhere near your intelligence its a gift bro which you have in abundance and what I have  a little with which I try to make do

Comment: I am working on something else at the moment, I will get back to you. I am thinking the problem is to do with CSS clashes like you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. One of my CSS style sheets had this setting;

```
table {
    margin: 1em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: inherit;
}
```

So I removed the margin, the problem is solved and an important lesson is learnt about generic style settings like the one above.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, but only when the jQgrid is rendered as a subgrid. The style on the table cell containing the filter reset icon was set to one pixel. The following jQuery resolved the issue for jqGrid 4.15.5 - free:

```
$("td.ui-search-clear").attr('style', 'width:10px;');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 grid.jqGrid({

}).navGrid('#grid', {search: true}
```

Write search:true in your filterGrid

Comment: This is not the answer as the search buttons exist, but they are mostly not visible because the table cells they are in are not wide enough to display them.

Comment: I have solved this issue in my project Update latest js and CSS of jqgrid  [click hear](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/tree/master)

Comment: That is the paid version which I cannot get. In truth the free version is very good, apart from this glitch.